# How to remove "unused space" from tab host?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I set scrollable tab widget but below tabs there is some unused space. I don't know how to remove space below tabs.

My xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </TabWidget>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Home_feed"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment4"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment5"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->


<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

> [image]

Comment: Do not use RelativeLayout anywhere in the tabs layout. Use only LinearLayout.

Comment: what is info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match ????

Comment: it is a list item shown snap-shot

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </TabWidget>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Home_feed"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment4"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment5"
                android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: it's list item as shown in snap-shot...u need code for that...??

Comment: my actual view is like this ..I updated it...there are navigation drawer is there and bottom most list view is contain item of navigation drawer....so is it making any different here..???